# Using tk.Scrollbar to update images in tk.canvas

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, scrollbar, tkinter-canvas, tkinter.scrollbar

I developed a small `tkinter` GUI to display (and export) images stored in a proprietary format. I managed to load the data into a 3D numpy `uint8` array. I want to display one slice of that 3D array in a `tkinter.canvas`. To do so I used `ImageTk.PhotoImage`.

Underneath the Canvas I inserted a `tk.Scrollbar`. My goal is to use that scrollbar to let the user actively "scroll" though the 3D Array. Basically when the slider is moved or any of the arrows is pressed the slice corresponding to the slider position should be displayed in the canvas.

Right now I have the issue that I don't understand how to set the range of the scrollbar to my z-Dimension and then how to bind the scrollbar events to the movement or arrow actions to update the canvas.

Right now I don't have example code since this is a more conceptual problem.

Could you point me in the right direction how to solve this?

Best TMC

edit: Photo

[Tkinter Gui with Canvas and Scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSPjP.png)

Comment: Descriptions of code are largely useless, and links to code on other sites is discouraged. Please try to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use `tkinter.Scale` instead of  `tkinter.Scrollbar` . As a side note, the command within:

`scale = tk.Scale(yourTkFrame, from_=min, to=max, orient='horizontal', command=doSomething)`

passes two values to the function `doSomething`.

Using the Scale allows to use the `scale.get()` method to retrieve the position between min and max values. Those can then be used to set the image corresponding to the selected position on the slide.